# Istio on minikube - envoy missing listener for inbound application port: 9095

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, istio, envoyproxy

I follow [this](https://medium.com/devopslinks/istio-step-by-step-part-03-deploying-an-application-with-istio-in-kubernetes-d2b1de64fb6b) istio tutorial (part 3). After I created minikube local registry, I need to run the following command:

```
kubectl run hellodemo --image=hellodemo:v1 --port=9095 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

Which should run image and istio-proxy on the Pod. 
When I run `kubectl get pods`, I get:

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hellodemo-6d49fc6c51-adsa1   1/2     Running   0          1h
```

When I run `kubectl logs  hellodemo-6d49fc6c51-adsa1 istio-proxy`:

```
* failed checking application ports. listeners="0.0.0.0:15090","10.110.201.202:16686","10.96.0.1:443","10.104.103.28:15443","10.104.103.28:15031","10.101.128.212:14268","10.104.103.28:15030","10.111.177.172:443","10.104.103.28:443","10.109.4.23:80","10.111.177.172:15443","10.104.103.28:15020","10.104.103.28:15032","10.105.175.151:15011","10.101.128.212:14267","10.96.0.10:53","10.104.103.28:31400","10.104.103.28:15029","10.98.84.0:443","10.99.194.141:443","10.99.175.237:42422","0.0.0.0:9411","0.0.0.0:3000","0.0.0.0:15010","0.0.0.0:15004","0.0.0.0:8060","0.0.0.0:9901","0.0.0.0:20001","0.0.0.0:8080","0.0.0.0:9091","0.0.0.0:80","0.0.0.0:15014","0.0.0.0:9090","172.17.0.6:15020","0.0.0.0:15001"
* envoy missing listener for inbound application port: 9095
2019-05-02T16:24:28.709972Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: 2 errors occurred:

* failed checking application ports. listeners="0.0.0.0:15090","10.110.201.202:16686","10.96.0.1:443","10.104.103.28:15443","10.104.103.28:15031","10.101.128.212:14268","10.104.103.28:15030","10.111.177.172:443","10.104.103.28:443","10.109.4.23:80","10.111.177.172:15443","10.104.103.28:15020","10.104.103.28:15032","10.105.175.151:15011","10.101.128.212:14267","10.96.0.10:53","10.104.103.28:31400","10.104.103.28:15029","10.98.84.0:443","10.99.194.141:443","10.99.175.237:42422","0.0.0.0:9411","0.0.0.0:3000","0.0.0.0:15010","0.0.0.0:15004","0.0.0.0:8060","0.0.0.0:9901","0.0.0.0:20001","0.0.0.0:8080","0.0.0.0:9091","0.0.0.0:80","0.0.0.0:15014","0.0.0.0:9090","172.17.0.6:15020","0.0.0.0:15001"
* envoy missing listener for inbound application port: 9095
2019-05-02T16:24:30.729987Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: 2 errors occurred:

* failed checking application ports. listeners="0.0.0.0:15090","10.110.201.202:16686","10.96.0.1:443","10.104.103.28:15443","10.104.103.28:15031","10.101.128.212:14268","10.104.103.28:15030","10.111.177.172:443","10.104.103.28:443","10.109.4.23:80","10.111.177.172:15443","10.104.103.28:15020","10.104.103.28:15032","10.105.175.151:15011","10.101.128.212:14267","10.96.0.10:53","10.104.103.28:31400","10.104.103.28:15029","10.98.84.0:443","10.99.194.141:443","10.99.175.237:42422","0.0.0.0:9411","0.0.0.0:3000","0.0.0.0:15010","0.0.0.0:15004","0.0.0.0:8060","0.0.0.0:9901","0.0.0.0:20001","0.0.0.0:8080","0.0.0.0:9091","0.0.0.0:80","0.0.0.0:15014","0.0.0.0:9090","172.17.0.6:15020","0.0.0.0:15001"
* envoy missing listener for inbound application port: 9095
```

Do you know what is the problem that prevent the istio-proxy container to come up?

I use istio-1.1.4 on minikube.

Comment: please run `kubectl describe <your pod>`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. I followed the documentation, and it said to enable SDS in the gateway. However, I enabled it in the gateway and also at the global scope as well, and this caused the error above.

I removed the following code from my values.yml file and everything worked:

```
global:
  sds:
    enabled: true
```